# Entity Framework 6 Database First and SQLite composite foreign key

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

I have a sqlite database with two tables, defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LocalQuotation (
  Id TEXT
  , Name TEXT NOT NULL
  , Author TEXT NOT NULL
  , Customer TEXT
  , RUA TEXT
  , ProjectName TEXT
  , CreationDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  , LastUpdateDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  , LastEditor TEXT NOT NULL
  , Reviewer TEXT
  , CacheData BLOB NOT NULL
  , Status INTEGER NOT NULL
  , Version INTEGER
  , PRIMARY KEY (Id, Version)
);

CREATE TABLE LocalParameter (
  Name TEXT
  , Data BLOB NOT NULL
  , RefQuotation TEXT
  , QuotationVersion INTEGER
  , PRIMARY KEY (Name, RefQuotation, QuotationVersion)
  , FOREIGN KEY (RefQuotation, QuotationVersion) REFERENCES LocalQuotation(Id, Version)
);
```

I am trying to map these tables with `Entity Framework 6 Database first`, but I get the following errors:

- Error 6035: The relationship 'FK_LocalParameter_0_0' has columns that
  are not part of the key of the table on the primary side of the
  relationship. The relationship was excluded.
- Error 6035: The relationship 'FK_LocalParameter_0_1' has columns that
  are not part of the key of the table on the primary side of the
  relationship. The relationship was excluded.

The message is quite clear, but I disagree with it. I can't see what columns are not in the primary key of `LocalQuotation`.

Is this a EF6's bug or a little typo I can't see ?

**EDIT**

Everything works perfectly when my foreign key was on a single colum, so I don't think it's a configuration problem, but here are the packages I am actually using:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="EntityFramework.fr" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.103" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.103" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.103" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.103" targetFramework="net452" />
```

And the config file:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
     <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is contributing to your problem, but text fields are bad choices for primary keys due to how they're stored and how much data may have to be compared for equality. In Microsoft SQL Server (which I know isn't SQLite) a text-type PK is not even allowed. Make sure that SQLite really is setting Id as a primary key field. Even if it is, you'll probably get EF to play ball better if you use an identity int or GUID column.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no GUID type in SQLite (I miss SQL Server :D). I know TEXT is not the best choice for a PK but in my case, this is not a problem ^^.

Comment: And yes, SQLite does set TEXT as a PK since it was working before I add Version as part of the PK.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @KimBayAndersen Unfortunately, I don't work for the company I worked back in the days of this question and I don't remember which solution I choose… I guess I didn't find a good solution otherwise I would have submitted it here. My guess is that I keep a single FK and use a unique constraint on the other columns to ensure the uniqueness of each entry. I am sorry for not helping you much.